# Soap service header <s:mustUnderstand in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I created web service to accept this soap request. 
I tested and Its working fine without header 
if I add header still working  for s:mustUnderstand="0" but 
if I change  it to 1 it's breaking

> Action s:mustUnderstand="1"

in order to accept header what changes I need to do on my web service?
Thanks in advance

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.xxxx-ccc.co.uk/Integration/SaveApplication</Action> </s:Header>  

<s:Body>  applicant>
          <title>Mr</title>
          <forename>dd</forename>
          <surname>ee</surname>
          <address>
            <street1>ppp</street1>
            <town>dd</town>
            <county>cc</county>
            <postcode>rtrtr</postcode>
          </address>
        </applicant> 
</s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

This is my web service code

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.xxxx-ccc.co.uk/Integration/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class CG_ADNContact : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(Description = "")]
        public XmlDocument SaveApplication()
        { //Do some thing }

}
```

Comment: Hello Have you figured this out? I have the exact problem. What did you change in the wcf service to be accept musunderstand =1

Comment: In Nov 2020 this is still a problem. I can confirm The WCF proxy will automatically generate the  soap:header as you stated, and it's actually submitted across the wire (if the MessageInspectors infrastructure provided by Microsoft is to be believed). I created MessageInspectors on BOTH the client-side (just prior to POST), and server-side (just after POST message received). The weird thing is, if using a standard HTTP post, the service always returns a 400-Error UNLESS that SOAP:Header with Action MustUnderstand=1 is removed !

Answer (score 4):

The `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none` namespace is not valid for an `Action` element. It should never be in a soap message. Where did you get the message from? Did you perhaps copy it from a wcf trace log?

If the `mustUnderstand` attribute is set to true (or 1), this basically means that the element in question has to be part of the service contract. You can control this with the `MustUnderstand` property of the `MessageHeader` attribute.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageheaderattribute.mustunderstand(v=vs.110).aspx) For an example service contract that uses this attribute.